# How to test a map and list in the same test case in Scala

Tags: scala

I want to test multiple methods, one that outputs a map and one that outputs a list. I have two separate test cases for each method, but I want a way to combine them and test both methods at the same time.

```
 test("test 1 map") {
    val testCases: Map[String, Map[String, Int]] = Map(
      "Andorra" -> Map("la massana" -> 7211)
    )
    for ((input, expectedOutput) <- testCases) {
      var computedOutput: mutable.Map[String, Int] = PaleBlueDot.cityPopulations(countriesFile, citiesFilename, input, "04")
      assert(computedOutput == expectedOutput, input + " -> " + computedOutput)
    }
  }
  test(testName="test 1 list") {
    val testCases: Map[String, List[String]] = Map{
      "Andorra" -> List("les escaldes")
    }
    for ((input, expectedOutput) <- testCases) {
      var computedOutput: List[String] = PaleBlueDot.aboveAverageCities(countriesFile, citiesFilename, input)
      assert(computedOutput.sorted == expectedOutput.sorted, input + " -> " + computedOutput)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is better to use a `List` rather than a `Map` for `testCases` as a `Map` can return values in any order. Using `List` ensures that tests are done in the order they are written in the list.

You can then make `testCases` into a `List` containing a tuple with test data for both tests, like this:

```
test("test map and list") {
  val testCases = List {
    "Andorra" -> (Map("la massana" -> 7211), List("les escaldes"))
  }
  for ((input, (mapOut, listOut)) <- testCases) {
    val computedMap: mutable.Map[String, Int] =
      PaleBlueDot.cityPopulations(countriesFile, citiesFilename, input, "04")
    val computedList: List[String] =
      PaleBlueDot.aboveAverageCities(countriesFile, citiesFilename, input)

    assert(computedMap == mapOut, input + " -> " + computedMap)
    assert(computedList.sorted == listOut.sorted, input + " -> " + computedList)
  }
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error type mismatch saying found : Map[String,Int] (in scala.collection.mutable) 
 required: Map[String,Int] (in scala.collection.immutable) . Does this error occur because I created an empty map in my code?

Comment: No, it's because I removed the `mutable` from the first test. I'll put it back. But pretty poor to return a mutable object from a library function.